# Drag and drop from dynamically objects

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drag-and-drop

I created a reusable User Control and I implement the method for drag and drop. (basically only the drag). I'm dynamically creating a list of these user controls inside a FlowLayoutPanel and I want to drag something from one of these control outside the FlowLayoutPanel container.

How can I do that? I can drag but when move the mouse outside the object for which I implemented the drag (mousedownEvent and DragEnter events) the cursor become a deny cursor and it doesn't work. I tried to design a label outside the FlowLayoutPanel and implement the DragDrop event but it doesn't work.

This is the code on the user control:

```
    public void projectLabel_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }

    public void projectLabel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        projectLabel.DoDragDrop(projectLabel.Text, DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
```

This is on main form:

```
    public void label2_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString());
    }
```

And this is how I fill the list of controls:

```
    private void SchedulerMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Populate the availableProjectList

        Scheduler.common.ProjectContainer projectContainer = new Scheduler.common.ProjectContainer();
        projectContainer.AllowDrop = true;
        projectContainer.projectName = "TEST";
        projectContainer.currentCounter = "1";
        projectContainer.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 128);

        availableProjectList.Controls.Add(projectContainer);

        Scheduler.common.ProjectContainer projectContainer2 = new Scheduler.common.ProjectContainer();
        projectContainer2.AllowDrop = true;
        projectContainer2.projectName = "TEST 2";
        projectContainer2.currentCounter = "1";
        projectContainer2.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(128, 128, 255);

        availableProjectList.Controls.Add(projectContainer2);



    }
```

AllowDrag is set to true on all objects

My question is: how can I drag the object from a dynamically create object inside a container to another object outside the container but on the same form?

thanks guys

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 'dynamically create object'. I assume it contains the drag and drop event build in from .NET so. How about some code

Comment: Make sure the control onto which you're dropping has its `AllowDrop` property set to `true`.

Comment: You need to handle the DragOver event in addition to the DragEnter event.  The default DragOver behavior is probably canceling the drop effect immediately after you set it in DragEnter.

Comment: Allow drop on the label?

Comment: Putting the comments from @Sievajet and @RogerN together, you must set `AllowDrop` on the **receiving** control to true and handle its `DragEnter` event to allow the drop to proceed.